# Linux Kernel - Socket file descriptor close location

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel

Where in the linux kernel does the closing of a socket's file descriptor occur? I know for a file, the file's file descriptor is closed in fs/open.cs function sys_close(). However, for a socket file descriptor, is this the same location or somewhere else?

Also, do sockets utilize the file.c alloc_fd to allocate the file descriptor or do they utilize some other function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, `sys_close()` is the entry point for closing *all* file descriptors, including sockets.

`sys_close()` calls `filp_close()`, which calls `fput()` on the `struct file` object.  When the last reference to the `struct file` has been put, `fput()` calls the file object's `.release()` method, which for sockets, is the `sock_close()` function in `net/socket.c`.

The socket code uses `get_unused_fd()` and `put_unused_fd()` to acquire and release file descriptors.

Comment: And I see get_unused_fd calls alloc_fd so by changing my code as needed in sys_close and alloc_fd, this should handle all file descriptors for files and sockets, correct?